# Django template shows only last file, instead of all uploaded

Tags: python, django

I want that for every lecture, the user to be able to upload multiple files, so I created a model that has FileField. So in my template, I want that for every lecture, the files uploaded to a particular lecture, to be shown in template. The Issue is that only the last uploaded file will show.

```js
  <ul>
        {% regroup lectures by get_lecture_category_display as category_list %}
        <h3>Lectures</h3>
        <ul>
            {% for category in category_list %}
                <strong>
                    <li>{{ category.grouper }}</li>
                </strong>
                <ul>
                    {% for c in category.list %}
                        .............
                        <li>{{ c.lecture_title }}</li>
                        <li>{{ c.content }}</li>
                        {% if c.files %}
                            <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ c.files.files.url }}'>download</a></li>
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </ul>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </ul>
```

```css
def courses(request, slug):
    query = Course.objects.get(slug=slug)
    context = {'courses': Course.objects.filter(slug=slug),
               'lectures': query.lectures.order_by('lecture_category'),
               }
    return render(request, 'courses/courses.html', context)
```

```html
class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
    lecture_category = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, "Classes "),
                                                    (1, "Seminars"),
                                                    ), default=0)
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    files = models.ForeignKey('FileUpload', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, )

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lecture_category)


class FileUpload(models.Model):
    files = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.files)

    def file_link(self):
        if self.files:
            return "<a href='%s'>download</a>" % (self.files.url,)
        else:
            return "No attachment"

    file_link.allow_tags = True
    file_link.short_description = 'File Download'
```

If I change to a ManytoManyField, also doesn't work. I need advice. But also in admin panel, if I wanna add a new lecture, the previous files from other lectures show as well, I don't know how to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You put `ForeignKey` in the wrong place. It should be the opposite:

```
class FileUpload(models.Model):
    uploaded_file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey('Lecture', related_name='files')
```

Now, one lecture can have many file uploads. Then, in your template you can iterate over your files:

```
{% for file in c.files.all %}
   <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.upploaded_file.url }}'>download</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem! One more question, when I save a Lecture, it says "Lecture 0 has been saved!". I think its due the choices field. How do I change that ?

Comment: @Daniel change your `__str__` method for something more meaningful.

Comment: If I remove the str, I get __str__ returned non-string (type int)

Comment: @Daniel I think you misunderstood. What do you want to change "Lecture 0 has been saved!" to? What should it say?

Comment: Yes, u were right. I was returning wrong attribute, instead of title, i was returning category. Everything its solved, thanks! Question got solved, but someone downvoted....

Answer (score 0):

ForeignKey create many-to-one relation. This means that now you can have many lecture with the same image but not many image of the same lecture. 
To fix this you can can use many-to-many relation:

```
files = models.models.ManyToManyField('FileUpload')
```

and in template:

```
{% for file in c.files.all %}
    <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.url }}'>download</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

Also you can reverse many-to-one relation as in Jahongir Rahmonov answer. This will allow to add many files for one lecture.

Answer (score 0):

Your foreign key relation is wrong. according to your current models, your lecture table will only reference to last uploaded file for a particular lecture.

your code should look like.

```
#models.py
class Lecture(models.Model):
    course = models.ForeignKey('Course', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', related_name='lectures')
    lecture_category = models.IntegerField(choices=((0, "Classes "),
                                                    (1, "Seminars"),
                                                    ), default=0)
    lecture_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.lecture_category)

class FileUpload(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents', null=True, blank=True)
    lecture = models.ForeignKey('Lecture', related_name='files')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.file)
```

and then in template you can do

```
{% for file in c.file_set.all %}
    <li><a href='{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ file.url }}'>download</a></li>
{% endif %}
```

also if you want to upload files directly from lecture model you can customise your **ModelAdmin** class in *admin.py* using [InlineModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects).